# Importing jquery in spfx application

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have followed the below steps to start using jquery in spfx.

1. Install the typings for jQuery:

   `npm install --save @types/jquery`
2. Update the config.json in the config folder to load jQuery from CDN. Add an entry to the externals field:

   `"jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"`
3. Import jQuery in your web part:

   `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Upto step 2 my application is working fine but after adding step 3 I start getting error:-

```
Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(2960,62):error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
[13:44:35] Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 1.68 s
TypeScript error(s) occurred.
```

Answer (score 4):

If I’m not wrong, jQuery@3 and its type definitions require a newer version of TypeScript which you can’t use in SPFx. Instead you should use jQuery@2 and @types/jquery@2

Answer (score 2):

In SPFX solution, please use Jquery-2.2.4.js instead:

```
"jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js",
"simpleWeather": {
  "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js",
  "globalName": "jQuery"
}
```

Official Reference:
[Use existing JavaScript libraries in SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

3.5.0 works fine in August 2023 with TypeScript v5.3.0 and @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.15.2

> "externals": {
> "jquery": {
> "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js",
> "globalName": "jQuery"
> }